# Android Async Group of Async Tasks finished

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an android function that calls multiple async requests. I want to know when all have finished. I saw onPostExecute() but that only tells me if one has finished. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way is to create a counter variable, e.g. `int taskCount`, and set it to the number of `AsyncTask`s you need to run before executing. Then create a method that will decrement the counter, and call it from the `onPostExecute()` method of each task. When `taskCount == 0`, the tasks will have completed.

A very simple example:

```
int taskCount;

private void startTasks()
{
    Task task1 = new Task();
    Task task2 = new Task();
    Task task3 = new Task();

    taskCount = 3;

    task1.execute();
    task2.execute();
    task3.execute();    
}

private void taskDone()
{
    taskCount--;
    if (taskCount == 0)
    {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "All done!", 0).show();
    }
}

private class Task extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        taskDone();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That tasks will take longer since AsyncTask only execute each task 1 at a time compare to a handler, and still #Mike's answer will still be applicable if you use a handler.